# how do you join two tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have a mysql query which is trying to join to tables to show the data from two tables onto one table on the webpage?

```
<?php
include 'library/connect.php';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM meetings INNER JOIN rooms USING ('room', 'date', 'time' ) ");

echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Title</th><th>Chairman</th><th>Secretary</th><th>Terms of Reference</th><th>Named membership</th><th>Occurences</th><th>Room</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['title']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['chairman']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['secretary']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['termsOfReference']. "</td>";        
        echo "<td>" . $row['occurences']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['room']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['date']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['time']. "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
include 'library/closedb.php';
?>
```

do i need both table id somewhere?

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get a result if you run the query as is?

Comment: `USING` is not the proper syntax.  it should be `ON` and comparison clauses.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: MySQL supports the USING join syntax. See the [JOIN documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for details.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli: so it does, which is something I did not know.  Still, it looks like it's legacy syntax, so I'd still recommend going with a more common `ON` clause.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: it's not legacy like implicit joins are legacy; `USING` was introduced in SQL-92, along with explicit joins. However, `USING` doesn't have as widespread support as `ON`, so shouldn't be used in case the RDBMS ever needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd doubt that `date` and `time` are columns in your `rooms` table, so they shouldn't be part of the JOIN condition. Try:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM meetings m
        INNER JOIN rooms r
            ON m.room = r.room
```

Comment: am getting this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in E:\webareas\bj115\year3\EWSD\MeetingSystem\secretary.php on line 60

Comment: It is only checking 'room' column. You havn't given conditions for 'date', 'time' columns.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Read the first sentence of my answer! I do not believe that `date` and `time` would be valid columns in the `rooms` table and therefore should not participate in the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

By "Using" keyword it will check both tables by column names. It will check inner join on Ist condition then it will get left join on next columns if result not found.

it's bad practice to use "Using" keyword.

Simplify joins by USING.
By

-[Multiple columns](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0140__Table-Joins/Usingtwocolumnsduringtablejoin.htm)

-[Single column](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0140__Table-Joins/SimplifyingJoinswiththeUSINGKeyword.htm)